# Why recursive data doesn't correctly insert parent_id?

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to insert recursive data into MYSQL using CodeIgniter. But inserting `parent_id` is not fully working. Only inserted last created auto increment id as `parent_id`. I am stuck, how do I fully insert?

Suppossed be like this-> https://i.stack.imgur.com/4alse.jpg

But now -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/MStxw.jpg

Inserting code:

```php
public function addProductVariant($product_id, $org_id, $categories, $parent_id=0){

    $this->db->where(['product_id'=>$product_id])->delete('product_to_org_addons');

    foreach ($categories as $category){
        foreach ($category as $variant) {
            $variant->product_id = $product_id;
            $variant->org_id = $org_id;
            $variant->parent_id = $parent_id;
            $this->db->insert('product_to_org_addons', $variant);

        }
        $parent_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your output is the same as your expectation - did you upload or link the wrong pictures?

Comment: Sorry i just edited.

Comment: @muug6i elaborate more on this. Unclear what you need and what you tried

Comment: @muug6i I might be missing something, but the expectation still matches the output.